# How to stream with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

How to properly stream response in ASP.NET Core? 
There is a controller like this (**UPDATED CODE**):

```
[HttpGet("test")]
public async Task GetTest()
{
    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Response.Body))
        await writer.WriteLineAsync("Hello World");            
}
```

Firefox/Edge browsers show

> Hello World

, while Chrome/Postman report an error:

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.
>
> ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

P.S. I am about to stream a lot of content, so I cannot specify Content-Length header in advance.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

To stream a response that should appear to the browser like a downloaded file, you should use `FileStreamResult`:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileStreamResult GetTest()
{
  var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World"));
  return new FileStreamResult(stream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"))
  {
    FileDownloadName = "test.txt"
  };
}
```

Comment: Actually my data source is not a `Stream` - it is SomeReader or IEnumerable. I will need a `Stream` adaptor then, which is pretty cumbersome. Is there an easy way to just write to `Response.Body`?
P.S. It does work in Chrome for some guys :)

Comment: @DmitryNogin: I wrote a [`FileCallbackResult` that may do what you need](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/11/streaming-zip-on-aspnet-core.html).

Comment: Outdated with latest version of .net core.

Comment: @emirhosseini: `FileStreamResult` doesn't exist in the latest version?

Comment: Tested @StephenCleary 's `FileCallbackResult` with Asp.Net Core 3.1 and it streams continuous results to the consumer as the other `StreamWriter` answers here do. It's basically a replacement for the old `PushStreamContent`. Does not necessarily appear to consumer as a file..but as a stream of text (or whatever).

Comment: But this copies an existing read-stream to the body stream. How to write to the body stream directly?

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis: I wrote a [`FileCallbackResult` that may do what you need](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/11/streaming-zip-on-aspnet-core.html).

Comment: @emirhosseini  You may just use  return new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/plain")

Comment: How to stream the part of byte to the front end for video player

Comment: @MohanRajRaja: Designing a video streaming solution is really a different kind of question.

Comment: @emirhosseini you comment isn't helpful at all without you naming the new solution :-\

Answer (score 22):

@Developer4993 was correct that to have data sent to the client before the entire response has been parsed, it is necessary to `Flush` to the response stream. However, their answer is a bit unconventional with both the `DELETE` and the `Synchronized.StreamWriter`. Additionally, Asp.Net Core 3.x will throw an exception if the I/O is synchronous.
This is tested in Asp.Net Core 3.1:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task Get()
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    StreamWriter sw;
    await using ((sw = new StreamWriter(Response.Body)).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        foreach (var item in someReader.Read())
        {
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(item.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await sw.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming `someReader` is iterating either database results or some I/O stream with a large amount of content that you do not want to buffer before sending, this will write a chunk of text to the response stream with each `FlushAsync()`.
For my purposes, consuming the results with an `HttpClient` was more important than browser compatibility, but if you send enough text, you will see a chromium browser consume the results in a streaming fashion. The browser seems to buffer a certain quantity at first.

Where this becomes more useful is with the latest `IAsyncEnumerable` streams, where your source is either time or disk intensive, but can be yielded a bit at at time:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<EmptyResult> Get()
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    StreamWriter sw;
    await using ((sw = new StreamWriter(Response.Body)).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        await foreach (var item in GetAsyncEnumerable())
        {
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(item.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await sw.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

You can throw an `await Task.Delay(1000)` into either `foreach` to demonstrate the continuous streaming.

Finally, @StephenCleary 's `FileCallbackResult` works the same as these two examples as well. It's just a bit scarier with the `FileResultExecutorBase` from deep in the bowels of the `Infrastructure` namespace.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return new FileCallbackResult(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"), async (outputStream, _) =>
    {
        StreamWriter sw;
        await using ((sw = new StreamWriter(outputStream)).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            foreach (var item in someReader.Read())
            {
                await sw.WriteLineAsync(item.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await sw.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        outputStream.Close();
    });
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by someReader.Read()? can you please show the implementation?

Comment: @BigyanDevkota `someReader.Read()` is simply a placeholder for anything that knows how to iterate over a large source data and return small chunks of data without loading the entire source into memory first. Could be a `StreamReader` or `DbReader` or `GetAsyncEnumerable()` or your own implementation. The question is about streaming the data to a browser, not how to obtain the data.

Comment: i didnt have to implement that, this 3 lines worked for me using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Response.Body))
    {
        sw.Write("something"); sw.Flush();
    }, thanks though

Comment: Thank you @mdisibio. This was exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to return `null` or `EmptyResult()` (which are equivalent), even when previously writing to `Response.Body`. It may be useful if the method returns `ActionResult` to be able to use all the other results aswell (e.g. `BadQuery()`) easily.

```
[HttpGet("test")]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Response.Body))
    {
        sw.Write("something");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why is this an answer to the question?

Comment: Please try adding some explanation to answer that may help

Comment: I added explanation into the answer.

Comment: Downvoting. For starters, the code example will not produce streaming results - as was the question. Instead it only streams the data into a buffered response... Not really helpful for streaming a response. Second, the explanation that is there is not really relevant.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit older, but I couldn't find a better answer anywhere for what I was trying to do. To send the currently buffered output to the client, you must call `Flush()` for each chunk of content you would like to write. Simply do the following:

```cs
[HttpDelete]
public void Content()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    Response.ContentType = "text/html";

    // the easiest way to implement a streaming response, is to simply flush the stream after every write.
    // If you are writing to the stream asynchronously, you will want to use a Synchronized StreamWriter.
    using (var sw = StreamWriter.Synchronized(new StreamWriter(Response.Body)))
    {
        foreach (var item in new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, })
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            sw.Write($"<p>Hi there {item}!</p>");
            sw.Flush();
        }
    };
}
```

you can test with curl using the following command: `curl -NX DELETE <CONTROLLER_ROUTE>/content`

Comment: .Net Core doesn't have Flush capabilities

Comment: @AlreadyLost it doesn't work without `Flush()`, gives it a shot. [asp.net core 2.2]

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering as well how to do this, and have found out that 
the original question's code actually works OK on `ASP.NET Core 2.1.0-rc1-final`, neither Chrome (and few other browsers) nor JavaScript application do not fail with such endpoint.

Minor things I would like to add are just set StatusCode and close the response Stream to make the response fulfilled:

```
[HttpGet("test")]
public void Test()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    using (Response.Body)
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Response.Body))
        {
            sw.Write("Hi there!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `using` statements are required? Doesn't ASP.NET Core dispose of them for you. Instead, I would expect you need to call `StreamWriter.Close` so that the final output gets flushed. (`Dispose` doesn't flush.)

Comment: @EdwardBrey while I agree that the "using" on Response.Body is not needed, can you back-up your statement on StreamWriter? The code seems to just call Dispose(true) on Close() (.Net: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs#L231 .NetCore: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs#L173 ). It would be very unreasonable otherwise in my opinion.

Answer (score -2):

something like this might work:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTest()
{
    var contentType = "text/plain";
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World")))
    return new FileStreamResult(stream, contentType);

}
```

Comment: Your code will not work because you dispose source stream before it gets used.

Comment: Still not good because, technically, the stream won't get read until after this method has returned. However, given that a `MemoryStream`'s `Dispose` doesn't dispose of the contents of the stream, you'll get away with it here. With real IO, you probably won't be so lucky.

Comment: ...actually, `FileStreamResult` disposes the stream it was passed when it has finished. The `using` statement here is completely superfluous.