# web api return too long string result outofmemory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, stringbuilder

I have a asp.net web api, the result string is very long, sometimes, out of memory exception will happen. How to avoid it!

in the controller.cs

```
 // GET: /XXXX/DetailJson/5
 private ActionResult DetailJson()
 {
     //some times the ret string is too much long,out of memory exception will raise,
     string ret=stub.getResultString();
     return Content(ret, "text/plain",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
 }
```

in  the stub.cs

```
 String getResultString()
 {
    StringBuilder ret="";
    ..........
    //sometimes the ret is very big,has very long length System.OutOfMemoryException will raise  !!!!
    return ret.ToString();
 }
```

> [OutOfMemoryException:trigger type  “System.OutOfMemoryException”
> exception]    System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString() +36

How to avoid such case?

Comment: Make it shorter? About how big are we talking about exactly? (min/avg/max)

Comment: Have you considered: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-5.0#return-large-collections-across-multiple-smaller-pages , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-5.0#minimize-large-object-allocations, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-5.0#compress-responses ?

Comment: Write parts of the string directly to the response like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62929137/1479335

Comment: Avoid reading large request bodies or response bodies into memory. how to keep avoid it!
If I want to read a  large file content,   do some business logic for the content  and return json result as string  in web api.In client side javascript will deal with the json result.

Comment: Can you show more code in `stub.cs` ? Does it read file then return string ?

Comment: yes ,just the same business logic   ,it will read a very large  files etc.more than 200MB ，and return all the text at once

Comment: @difeijin Does your file type is .txt ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code to read your .txt file. I can read it successfully, but it can't response to browser, because read file.txt use more than 5min.

[image]

```
public string getResultString()
{
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    //file in disk
    var FileUrl = @"E:\WebApplication1\file.txt";
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileUrl))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                ret.Append(line);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    return ret.ToString();
}
```