# Headers are read-only Exception Message is thrown When Trying to Stream a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, video-streaming

I have a controller method that is intended to stream a video file stored in a database. But when the method is called, I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.

From a little digging, I learned that the response headers cannot be modified when the response has begun. But from my code below, I still don't see what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

```
[HttpGet("stream/{id}")] 
public async Task<IActionResult> StreamFile(int id) 
{
    var upload = await _mediator.Send(new GetFileUploadByIdQuery { Id = id });
    if (upload.Data == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var contentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline")
    {
        FileName = upload.Data.FileName
    };

    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = upload.Data.ContentType;

    // Stream the file in chunks
    int chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
    int bytesRead;
    using var stream = new MemoryStream(upload.Data.Content);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize]; 
    while ((bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        await Response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: What line is the exception thrown?

Comment: Also, see the top answer on this one for a good file response pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460198/return-file-in-asp-net-core-web-api

Comment: @andyrut I'm trying to write the response to the body as stream, so I would be able to stream the video from a blazor application. I don't want to return a file as found in the link you posted.

Comment: Where does `Response` come from? Where is it declared and instantiated?

Comment: @Fildor It's from the HttpContext class.

Comment: Still not entirely clear to me. I am suspicious of an unintentional reuse issue. Does this happen every time or just sometimes?

Comment: @Fildor the code doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42772150/982149 also mind the comments

Comment: I think I was just overthinking it. It's even simpler than I thought. https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/partial-range-http-requests-with-aspnet-core This pointed me to the right direction.